# Asp.Net Core WebApi: Create Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit

I have an AccountController class, here its ctor:

```
public AccountController(
            UserManager<User> userManager,
            SignInManager<User> signInManager,
            RoleService roleService,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _roleService = roleService;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
```

**RoleService** it's my own class.

I created a xUnit Test project and use Entity Framework Core to avoid mocking and faking database. I use *UseInMemoryData* method:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .Options;
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
```

But i do not understand how can i test AccountController, witch injects `UserManager<User>, SignInManager<User>` and so on. How can i create instance of AccountController class?

Comment: Are you going for a full integration test, i.e. testing the whole `AccountController` alltogether including database access and http request pipeline?

Comment: You will create instances of that classes  - this will give perfect tests of your controller, which you can refactor alter without rewriting all tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally don't create Unit Test for Controllers, because We need mock a lot of things and it's a hard work.

If you think about that your controller only call another piece of code such as Application Service or a Command Handler you can cover your controller with integration tests, and create Unit Test for your Command Handlers or Application Service or any tier that you have your business logic.

But maybe if you really want to create a unit test to your controller you will needs create a mock of all dependencies that you need in your controllers using a framework like Moq.

I hope this help :D

Comment: _We need mock a lot of things_ and then _your controller only call another piece of code_ - does that mean that your service or handler will have a lot of mocks?

Comment: @Fabio When we try to create Controllers unit test we need mock things like HttpContext, IConfiguration and our dependencies like repositories, domain services, and others. If you think that your business lógic don't should be in your controllers you don't need to create unit tests for then.

Comment: You don't need to mock `HttpContext` unless you reading raw data from there. Repositories will be used by business logic objects as well, so you need to mock it for your business logic object as well.

Comment: To have unit tests which you don't rewrite every time you add parameter to some public method - mock only objects which makes tests slow - database access, file system other external resources.

Comment: Thinking about Test Value if you need mock everything in your controller, Instead test something that has a value you will testing only mocks! When you can test everything integrated, unless that you have business logic in the controller.